# Cut and paste Visio shape in macro

Tags: vba, visio

I'm trying to write a VBA macro that builds a basic diagram from data and certain template shapes (held on a separate page).  While I can cut and paste successfully, I seem to be unable to reference the new shape after I do this.  I can relocate the shape before I cut and paste it, but if I try to do anything after the fact, I hit a run-time error.  There are various reasons why I might need to move / update the objects later, so I need to be able to subsequently reference them.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim Shape as Visio.Shape
Dim ShapeID as Integer
 
‘copy shape from template page 2, ID 12
Set Shape = Application.ActiveDocument.Pages.ItemU("Page-2").Shapes.ItemFromID(12).Duplicate
 
ShapeID = Shape.ID
MsgBox ("Created shape ID: " & ShapeID)
      
'Now relocate the shape appropriately
currentX = startX + (Count * xSpacing)
currentY = startY
       
Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaForceU = "" & currentX & " mm"
Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaForceU = "" & currentY & " mm"
 
Shape.Cut
   
 'Now go to page 1 and paste the object
 
Application.ActiveDocument.Pages.ItemU("Page-1").Paste

‘*** THE FOLLOWING LINE THAT DOESN’T WORK ***
Set Shape = Application.ActiveDocument.Pages.ItemU("Page-1").Shapes.ItemFromID(ShapeID)
 
Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaForceU = "" & currentX & " mm"
Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaForceU = "" & currentY & " mm"
```

If I run the above, I get the error "Invalid sheet identifier" at the highlighted line (the shape is pasted successfully).  If I cut this line out, I get "an exception occurred" on the following line, so it looks like I've lost my reference to the object.

Answer (score 2):

A shape's ID is only unique to its page, so the new shape that you paste into Page-1 will receive a new ID and hence the error that you're receiving.  Although the `Duplicate` method returns a shape reference to the new shape, `Paste` does not so you need to get a reference to it by other means - either assuming something about the window selection (as per Surrogate's answer) or by index:

```
Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim pag As Visio.Page

Set pag = ActivePage 'or some alternative reference to Page-1
Set shp = pag.Shapes.ItemU(pag.Shapes.Count)
Debug.Print shp.Index
```

A more usual workflow would be to generate masters (in a stencil document) and then drop those masters rather than copying and pasting between pages, but your scenario may require a different approach.

I'll add this link as useful reference for dealing with Index and ID properties:

- [Working with Shape Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa201761(v%3Doffice.10))

[Update]

@Jon Fournier's comment below is quite right that the above does make assumptions.  For example, if the [`DisplayLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/displaylevel-cell-shape-layout-section) cell in the source shape is less than the top most shape then it will be pasted into the page's shapes collection at the corresponding index and so count won't return the correct shape ID.

An alternative approach might be to listen to the [`ShapeAdded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.pages.shapeadded) event on Pages (or Page).  The following is a slight adaption from the [`IsInScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.application.isinscope) example in the docs, with code placed ThisDocument.  This allows you to top and tail your code in an event scope ID pair that you can inspect when handling the ShapeAdded event:

```
Private WithEvents vPags As Visio.Pages
Private pastedScopeID As Long

Public Sub TestCopyAndPaste()

    Dim vDoc As Visio.Document
    Set vDoc = Me 'assumes code is in ThisDocument class module, but change as required

    Dim srcPag As Visio.Page
    Set srcPag = vDoc.Pages.ItemU("Page-2")

    Dim targetPag As Visio.Page
    Set targetPag = vDoc.Pages.ItemU("Page-1")

    Dim srcShp As Visio.Shape
    Set srcShp = srcPag.Shapes.ItemFromID(12)

    Set vPags = vDoc.Pages

    pastedScopeID = Application.BeginUndoScope("Paste to page")

    srcShp.Copy
    targetPag.Paste

    Application.EndUndoScope pastedScopeID, True

End Sub

Private Sub vPags_ShapeAdded(ByVal shp As IVShape)
    If shp.Application.IsInScope(pastedScopeID) Then
        Debug.Print "Application.CurrentScope " & Application.CurrentScope
        Debug.Print "ShapeAdded - " & shp.NameID & " on page " & shp.ContainingPage.Name
        DoSomethingToPastedShape shp
    Else
        Debug.Print "Application.CurrentScope " & Application.CurrentScope
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingToPastedShape(ByVal shp As Visio.Shape)
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        shp.CellsU("FillForegnd").FormulaU = "=RGB(200, 30, 30)"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don’t remember when, but I got burned assuming the pasted shape was last in the shapes collection

Comment: Thanks.  The big thing for me was discovering it's not the same reference on different pages.  This really clarifies what's going on.

Comment: Yes, good point @Jon.  Have updated answer with alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you get error "Invalid sheet identifier" ! Because at "Page-1" you can have shape with **ShapeID**, which you defined for shape placed at "Page-2".

You can paste shape and after this step define selected shape.

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Pages.ItemU("Page-1").Paste

' You can define this variable as shape which is selected
Set Shape = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
```

Why you use variable two times ?

Comment: Maybe I'm just not understanding how these methods work, but what I *thought* was happening here (and seems to work) is 1. Select item (on page 2).  2. Duplicate item (on page 2) and store the ID in ShapeID. 3. Cut the item. 4 Paste the item on page 1.  That all works in the above code, but then what I want to do is move the shape that I've pasted on page 1.  If I remove the problem line, Shape doesn't hold a reference at all (it seems to lose it at the paste).  If I put it in, I want it to find the one I pasted.

Comment: Sorry - didn't see you'd changed the code as well.  So the pasted item will be the selected one?  If so, that makes sense, but I don't quite understand why my code wouldn't also have worked.  Does a shape ID change if I move it between pages?

Comment: Yes, shape's ID changed when you paste it in another page. **ID** in general, is the number corresponding to the order of adding shapes to the page! Please read more about [Shape.ID Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.id), look at **Remarks**

Comment: Right.  That's the big thing I was missing.  Upvoted as explanation now makes sense to me and you've supplied code to solve the problem.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t found a great way to handle this. I have a method that will paste the clipboard to a page and return any new shapes, by listing all shape ids before and after pasting, and then returning new shapes.

If speed is a big issue for me I’ll usually paste to an empty hidden page, do whatever I have to on that page, then cut and paste in place on the destination page. If you need to glue with other shapes this wouldn’t really work, but when it makes sense I use this logic.

Comment: Glad it's not just me having the problem.  Speed is not an issue as the idea was to write a script that took a description of the flow I wanted and then build it once (I have a lot of these to draw and the requirements change daily, so it was a labour-saving idea). The solution below gives a way of identifying the pasted item, so it looks like I have a solution, but your workaround is also valid for my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Duplicate&Cut&Paste, just use Drop:

```
Dim srcShape, dstShape as Shape
Set srcShape = ActiveDocument.Pages("Page-2").Shapes("srcShape")
Set dstShape = ActiveDocument.Pages("Page-1").Drop(srcShape, 0, 0)
```

After the above you can access `dstShape` and do with it whatever you want.